# Find a set of numbes in long string using RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, search, digits

Ive been searching the Stackoverflow but couldnt find the exact thread that could help me.

My problem is this, i want to be able to find and take out any occurances of 8 digits wihtin a string.

```
Dim SetOfMatches As MatchCollection
Dim MyRegex As New Regex("A^\d{8}$A")
Dim TestString As String = "testing 12345678 testing"
myMatches = myRegex.Matches(TestString)

For each Row as Match in myMatches

console.writeline(row.value)

Next
```

this doesnt not generate any hits. but i want to find the 8 digit occurance in the middle of the string.

I am very basic in RegEx.

any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the `A` good for? I think you don't need them.

Try this

```
\d{8}
```

The `^` is an anchor for the start of the string and the `$` for the end. So using those it will not find and digits within the string.

Regexr.com is a good online testing tool, you can see [this regex here](http://regexr.com?2v236).

Another good source for regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Yes this sovled the problem. I just saw it. Thanks buddy!